# Data query in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, powerpoint

I'm reaching out to you with the following:

How can I create a preformatted powerpoint slideshow that updates values and certain texts based on a database, like sql, access?

I could create something like this with excel and then copy pasting excel objects that were formatted in excel on a separate worksheet, and it works fine, but it's kinda clunky because let's say there's a slide which has 8 possible rows of text like names. But today only 4 of those names are going to be presented so the other 4 cells are empty in the excel sheet, but in oder to proceed to the next slide I have to press next 4 more times because the animations are being played even with empty cells. This part is what I wanna solve the most!

I wanna forego this whole bunch of problems with a properly managed database which holds the values, and is changed from time to time but the formatting part is done in powerpoint, and somehow tell powerpoint that empty database rows don't have to be put into the slideshow.

I know there's the Add-in called DataPoint which seems like an awesome product, but at the moment I don't have 500 USD to spend on this project, and I know it is possible using VBA but I'm kinda newbie to that. (Also I'm paying for MS Office and I love it, but I feel like this is something that should be included as a basic feature.)

If you can give me a code sample and explain how it works or just direct me to someone who can, I'll learn the rest.

I know it's specific, but also there's the issue with the excel based solution, that PowerPoint for some reason keeps the whole file path to the xlx to what all the references inside are linked and not the relative position (like xlsx with name X in the same folder as the pptx itself.) This way it would make far more sense, because I'm working on a myriad of different machines and the file paths are rarely similar let alone the same. I was able to overcome this issue by recreating a file path on every machine that matches the original, but it's not a bit professional.

Any idea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can find many examples that show how to read data from a Database using ADO. That can be your starting point. Connect to your MDB (or SQL Server) and read a Recordset. From there you can populate your Powerpoint template with the data.

Comment: Here is a much less expensive add-in that merges data into a presentation: http://www.pptools.com/merge/FAQ00008.htm